# SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode

Tags: text, alignment

Can someone give me an example of how to use SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode?

Here's how I'm defining my label:

```
RunningLevelLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster" ];
RunningLevelLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",numberOfBonusAlienPoints];
RunningLevelLabel.fontSize = 36;
RunningLevelLabel.position = CGPointMake(-10,-50);  // offscreen
RunningLevelLabel.fontColor = [SKColor grayColor];

[StartScreenWindow addChild:RunningLevelLabel];
```

thanks,
rich

Answer (score 4):

First create a label:

```
  SKLabelNode *scoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Arial"];
  scoreLabel.text = @"00000";
  scoreLabel.fontSize  = 18;
  scoreLabel.fontColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  scoreLabel.position  = CGPointMake(200, 300);
  [self addChild: scoreLabel];
```

Now, you can align the label with:

```
 scoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeCenter;
```

**OR**

```
scoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeRight;
```

**OR**

```
scoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeLeft;
```

This outputs are shown in figure below:

[image]

Keep coding............. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hasn't been answered yet and I was just looking for this myself...
See the 2nd line...vertical alignment works the same way.

```
SKLabelNode  *RunningLevelLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster" ];
[RunningLevelLabel setHorizontalAlignmentMode:SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeCenter];

RunningLevelLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",numberOfBonusAlienPoints];
RunningLevelLabel.fontSize = 36;
RunningLevelLabel.position = CGPointMake(-10,-50);  // offscreen
RunningLevelLabel.fontColor = [SKColor grayColor];
[StartScreenWindow addChild:RunningLevelLabel];
```