# How can I set the alignment of a SKLabelNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I'm trying to keep the left side of an SKLabelNode fixed after updating it. The thing is that the SKLabelNode is growing in both directions. All I want is to grow only in the right side. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem is, that SKNodes have their origin in the center of their node. So you will have to set the SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode to "left" to resolve this problem.

```
var label:SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode()
label.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Left
```

Here a picture, what the different modes do:

[image]
[Link to picture origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684528/sklabelhorizontalalignmentmode)